# OneSignal push notification opens MainActivity, instead of opening the Launch URL

Tags: android, android-studio, onesignal

I have created a webview app on android. I use onesignal to send notification to users. But when a user clicks on notification - MainActivity class is opened, instead of opening the URL provided in the Launch URL field while sending notification.

```
package app.example.com;

import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // OneSignal Initialization
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();


        Log.d("OneSignalTag", "Before OneSignal init");

        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE);
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();

        Log.d("OneSignalTag", "After OneSignal init");
    }


}
```